# run window.open() in js performs different in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, tabs, window, window.open

We are developing a web application with javascript, we use chrome as our default browser for our users.
Now we met a problem when we use window.open in our application.

In our application, we need to open new page in a new browser tab, we used code : window.open('http://ourUrl.com', '_blank') in js code;

The action of the browser is different according to when this line of code is executed.

situation 1: user clicked a button, the click event will trigger our js function, in this function, execute this line of code directly, then the browser may open the page in a new browser tab. (this is what we want.)

situation 2: user clicked a button, in the handler of the button's click event, we firstly submit the data on page to our server via ajax, and in the callback function, we execute this line of code, it may pop an independent new window without tool bar instead of a browser tab.(this is not what we want).

I don't understand why the action of browser is different, anyone can help to explain?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As I explained on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16749907/window-open-behaviour-in-chrome-tabs-windows), in order for a URL to be opened in a new tab (not new window), the *window.open* function must be called within a scope of a user generated action callback (for example, within the scope of *onClick*)
In any other scenario, the URL will be opened in a new window.

To explain what you're experiencing:
**Situation 1:** *window.open* is invoked in a callback for a user generated action. That's why it's opened in a new tab.
**Situation 2:** In this situation, the *window.open* function is invoked in the scope of an ajax response callback, which is a different scope (outside the context of) the user generated action.

For the second scenario to open a new tab (instead of window) you need to call *window.open* synchronously, immediately after the user's click, and not as a callback of another action (ajax response).