# window.open opening tabs and windows in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, tabs, window.open

I have this JS function who activates when a button is clicked:

```
function redirect() {
        win = window.open(\"$ref\", target=\"_blank\");
        win2 = window.open(\"$ref\", target=\"_blank\");
        win3 = window.open(\"$ref\", target=\"_self\");
}
```

First call to window.open opens a new tab in Chrome, second window.open opens a new window and the third window.open successfully "redirects" the original window to $ref.

My question is: why the first and the second window.open open both a tab and a window? Is there any way to open only tabs?

Comment: Looks like it's explained in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16749907/window-open-behaviour-in-chrome-tabs-windows?rq=1

Comment: possible duplicate of [Open url in new tab using javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-url-in-new-tab-using-javascript)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A have solved this problem and create a [gist](https://gist.github.com/frontenddeveloping/7577049). It open 3 links in tabs.

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH!!! After looking for months, almost hundreds of posts here in StackOverflow, asking my teachers & friends about this, at last someone posted a valid solution. You have my eternal gratitude.

I was thinking something like that: creating some hidden structure holding the URLs I wanted to open in tabs and then emulating clicks in them to open in new tabs. But you managed to write it when I couldn't, so have my thanks ;)

Comment: One last question. I'm testing the code on IE but the line
    element.fireEvent('onclick', evt)
gives me an error in IE (SCRIPT16389: Unspecified error). Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: IE version? I will check the gist.

Comment: I managed to solve it checking if the navigator was IE and then entering in the same part of the loop as FF.