# How to open popup in datatable mrender?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, datatable

I want open popup new window in datatable mrender. but Running my code appear new tab is not new window.. How to fix my code?

in thin my code

```
 if (o.pay_coper_type == "test" ) {
 return '<form action="../test/test.php" method="post" target="popup" onsubmit="window.open("../test/test.php", "popup", "width=500, height=500"><input type="hidden" name="p_index" value="' + o.p_index + '" ><input type="submit"  value="print" ></form>'; }
```

Comment: Take a look at accepted answer here: [window.open behaviour in chrome tabs/windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16749907/window-open-behaviour-in-chrome-tabs-windows) Sounds like normal behavior now. People abused popups. I think a sort of workaround is to use a "dialogue window", you'll want to dynamically add something to the current DOM, possibly combining Xhr response handling.